# Putting the content of many columns in a new single column

Tags: r, dplyr, coalesce

Thanks for the answers to my previous question, but I need to update it, since the solutions don't work with my real life example, i.e., a 3170x11 dataframe.

Let me briefly recapitulate it. I have a 3170X11 dataframe, filled with the terms 'Normale', 'Delezioni' or NA. I would like to coalesce the column results in a new columns, reporting the type of term reported, that is indeed 'Normale', 'Delezioni' or 'NA'. In case 'Normale' and 'NA' are present on the same row, it should be reported 'Normale'. In case 'Delezioni' and 'NA' are present on the same row, it should be reported 'Delezioni'. In case only 'NA' are present should be reported 'NA'. However in case both 'Normali' and 'Delezioni' are present, it should be reported 'Error'. Akrun and others reported a nice solution ([Coalescing many columns into one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741824/coalescing-many-columns-into-one-column)), but, as I said, doesn't work when things become bigger:

```
library (RCurl)
a <- getURL('http://download1645.mediafire.com/pp9z3okh5tgg/96px8ophovxrxe9/example.tab')
df2 <- read.table(text=a,header=TRUE, sep = "\t")
df2 <- data.frame(lapply(df2, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE) #converts from factor to character
res <- df2 %>%
   mutate_if(~ all(is.na(.)) && is.logical(.), ~ NA_character_) %>%
   transmute(Summary = case_when(rowSums(!is.na(.)) > 1 ~ "Error",
            TRUE ~ coalesce(!!! .)))
```

res contains several mistakes. For instance the first lines should be:

```
  Summary
1   Normale
2    <NA>
3    <NA>
4    <NA>
5   Normale
6   Normale
```

Instead they are:

```
> head (res)
  Summary
1   Error
2    <NA>
3    <NA>
4    <NA>
5   Error
6   Error
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can define a simple function which works based on your requirement

```
apply_fun <- function(x) {
  if(all(c("Delezioni","Normale") %in% x)) return('Error')
  if("Delezioni" %in% x) return('Delezioni')
  if("Normale" %in% x)  return('Normale')
  else NA
}
```

and then `apply` it row-wise

```
example$answer <- apply(example, 1, apply_fun)
head(example$answer)
#[1] "Normale" NA        NA        NA        "Normale" "Normale"
```

---

If needed a `tidyverse`/`dplyr` answer, we can convert these multiple `if` statements to `case_when` and then use `pmap`

```
library(tidyverse)

apply_fun <- function(x) {
  case_when(all(c("Delezioni","Normale") %in% x) ~ "Error", 
            "Delezioni" %in% x ~ "Delezioni", 
            "Normale" %in% x ~ "Normale", 
            TRUE ~NA_character_)
}

output <- example %>% mutate(answer = pmap_chr(., ~apply_fun(c(...))))
```

Comment: example$answer <- apply(example, 1, apply_fun)



Error in apply(example, 1, apply_fun) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length

Comment: @Arturo Are you using the correct dataframe name?  I am using `example`, I guess in your case it is `df2`. You also need to run `apply_fun` in your console so that the function is present in your environment.

Comment: Yes. Even with df2 thins don't change:

example$answer <- apply(df2, 1, apply_fun)

Error in example$answer <- apply(df2, 1, apply_fun) : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: `df2$answer <- apply(df2, 1, apply_fun)` works for me as shown for the data that you have shared in the link.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much to you and to the orther one who answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me, with the data set in the link.

```
f1 <- function(x){
  y <- unique(x[!is.na(x)])
  if(length(y) == 0) 
    NA 
  else if(length(y) == 1) 
    y 
  else "Error"
}

df2$Summary <- apply(df2, 1, f1)
```

And with no need for external packages, base R only.

Comment: Thanks, but there are errors. For instance the first element of df2$Summary, should be 'Normale', not 'Errors'.